# Laravel Inertia JS Flash Messages shows only once

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application, inertiajs

Because InertiaJS doesn't refresh same route components, things like flash messages will show only once no matter how many time you pass messages from the backend. I tried everything but nothing works, All I need is to be able to trigger the same flash message again after I fail doing the same action.

Controller:
This should be triggered as part of validation I'm making by some if statements, so basically I'm saying if the quantity requested more than stock quantity return this flash message.

```php
                    return back()->with([
                        'error' => 'This item has only ' . $item->qty . ' items in stock'
                    ]);
```

The flash component:

```js
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
defineProps({
    message: Object,
});

const showNotif = ref(false);

let msgs = ref([]);

onMounted(() => {
    showNotif.value = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
        showNotif.value = false;
    }, 6000);
});
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <Transition
            mode="out-in"
            name="flash"
            tag="div"
            enter-active-class="animate__animated animate__fadeInUp"
            leave-active-class="animate__animated animate__fadeOutDown"
            appear
        >
            <p
                v-if="message.error && showNotif"
                class="cursor-pointer fixed bottom-3 right-3 bg-red-600 px-5 py-1 font-semibold text-white rounded-xl"
            >
                {{ message.error }}
            </p>
        </Transition>
        <Transition
            mode="out-in"
            name="flash"
            tag="div"
            enter-active-class="animate__animated animate__fadeInUp"
            leave-active-class="animate__animated animate__fadeOutDown"
            appear
        >
            <p
                v-if="message.success && showNotif"
                class="cursor-pointer fixed bottom-3 right-3 bg-green-600 px-5 py-1 font-semibold text-white rounded-xl"
            >
                {{ message.success }}
            </p>
        </Transition>
    </div>
</template>
```

This works fine, the flash shows up, spent few seconds and then disappear. but no matter how many times I click on the same button to get this flash message it never happens and my brain is about to explode!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation [here](https://inertiajs.com/shared-data#flash-messages), You will have to look for `app/Http/Middleware/HandleInertiaRequests.php` and make sure you have something like this.

```
class HandleInertiaRequests extends Middleware
{
    public function share(Request $request)
    {
        return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
            'flash' => [
                'error' => fn () => $request->session()->get('error')
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Basically, you are creating a shared_data prop called flash, which is an associative array (Object) with a message key.

Note that you will only get data in your front end if you do `with(['error => 'message here'])`. If you want a `success` you will also have to add it on its own.

sample of the data you would get
[image]

Comment: The last sentence is relevant! I was tearing out my hair yesterday bc I did not read that far, so this morning, I figured it out myself. You have to use the array form of `with()`, it does not seem to work otherwise. This is the portion the Inertia docs somehow do not cover.